# how to create a new hash table

Tags: python-3.x, hashtable

I want to implement a new hash table with chaining as an array of lists.
Each object in this inter list will be an implementation of a new class that I created (called " search " ).
Can you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Help with what exactly? Does your code throw errors or do you have design questions? I may suggest you narrow down your problem to a specific question, and come back afterwards.

Comment: it was a design question actually, i thought you'll understand that because I didn't add any code (sorry about the miss understanding ).

Answer (score 0):

well I managed to do that by myself so thanks anyway.
after I've learned about hash tables in Java last year i thought it's kinda the same (a special object ) but actually it is just as array of list in python.

if someone else have a different way to do that I'd like to hear about it.